# How to import a file that imports different modules based on parameter

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file called "myfile.py" that prints out the name of the module it imports:
**myfile.py**

```py
import numpy as np
def foo():
    print(np.__name__)
```

and when I import myfile.py and run foo() from main.py, it outputs "numpy":
**main.py**

```
from myfile import *
foo()
>>> numpy
```

Now, I'd like to import `myfile` based on a variable called `cuda`: if `cuda` is `True`, then myfile should `import cupy as np` and `foo()` should prints out "cupy"; otherwise `import numpy as np` and `foo()` prints "numpy":

```
cuda = True
from myfile import *
foo()
>>> cupy
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it okay to pass a variable to `foo`? that way you could do the importation within `foo` based on a the value of the variable.

Comment: this is just a simple example, in my real case I have a lot more functions that uses `np`, so I want to run those functions using cupy if cuda is True otherwise use numpy.

Comment: It may be a bit hack-y but you still may be able to do what you want by including the following at the top of each function if you include `cuda` as variable to be passed: `if cuda: import cupy as np else: import numpy as np`. You can probably wrap that all into a helper function to make your code more modular. It may kill your efficiency if you are constantly importing cupy/numpy for each function call.

Comment: I think I came up with a better solution so I posted it as an answer. It is a bit annoying as you have to modify each function in `foo.py` and have to include another parameter in each function call. You can include the extra parameter in `**kwargs` to make your code neater.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works satifactorily.

You can simply pass `np` as a parameter to each function so that whatever definition of `np` you use in your main script is passed onto the module.

```
#foo.py 

def foo(np=None):
    print(np.__name__)
```

```
#main.py

from foo import *

import numpy as np
foo(np=np)

import cupy as np
foo(np=np)
```

will output

```
>>> numpy
>>> cupy
```